# How to check if one path exists under another path in the file system in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have two paths. I want to check if one of them exists under the other one in the file system. I would do something like:

```
if (index($path,$subpath) != -1 && $path ne $subpath) {
    print("$subpath is subpath of $path\n");
}
```

But treating the path as string result with some issues. For example if the `$path` or `$subpath` are links, it won't work.

What is a robust way to check if `$subpath` exists under the `$path`? In case it's a link, it should check if the link (source file and not the target) itself exists under that path.

For example:

```
Path (realpath to dir): /a/b/c
Subpath (realpath to dir): /a/b/c/d
```

In that case it the second one is under the file system of first one. Another example:

```
Path (realpath to dir): /a/b/c
Subpath: /p/x/y/z
```

Where `/p/x/y/z` is a link to `/a/b/c/d/e/f` for example. In that case it is not under the filesystem of the first path because the link is located in `/p/x/y/z` and not under `/a/b/c/...`. Hope it make sense.

Comment: Can you provide some example paths and subpaths (Both ones that exist and don't)?

Comment: @Shawn Add some examples. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Enough to give a answer, yeah (I wasn't sure if your subpath was absolute like `/a/b/c/d` or relative like `d`).

Comment: You can do `use Cwd; $path = Cwd::realpath( $path ); $subpath = Cwd::realpath( $subpath ); return( length( $subpath ) > length( $path ) && index( $subpath, $path ) == 0 );` which will tell you that `$subpath` is contained in `$path`.

Answer (score 3):

Using the very handy [`Path::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module:

```perl
use Path::Tiny;

...

my $path = path("/a/b/c");
my $subpath = path("/a/b/c/d");
if ($path->subsumes($subpath)) {
    # True if $path is a prefix of $subpath
    ...
}
```

You can use the [`realpath`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#realpath) method to resolve symlinks, `..`, etc. first if desired in one (Or both) paths:

```
my $path = path("/a/b/c")->realpath;
my $subpath = path("/p/x/y/z");
```